# How to edit vector points of multiple objects at a time?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

Is there a way to edit vector points of multiple separate vector objects at a time? I haven’t been able to find a way to do this in Sketch.

I created a short screencast of what I mean, done in Fireworks:
http://screencast.com/t/eh6tgC516a4

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is another gap in Sketch's functionality. As good as some users have gotten with it, it's definitely not an Illustration app.

The emerging power duo is Sketch + [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/), the later being squarely focused on vector illustration. The Affinity products are surprisingly mature, especially for the price. AD has the node selection functionality you're after.